# Computing a Gamma function-Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would like to compute the following function:

```
Integrate[Gamma[k,0,Exp[-2 e x^2]],x]
```

`k` is an integer and `e` a parameter. I would like to be able to have an closed form expression for it to fit a curve (actually to fit convolutions of this function, but it's the same), or at least a function to compute numerical approximate values, given the values of `k` and `e`.
I have tried `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`, but they do not work, and do not return a value or an expression.

Is there a way I can do this with *Mathematica*? Or maybe another software that could do it?

Comment: Do you know the integration limits?

Comment: Ideally, it would be from 0 to Infinity.

Comment: Even the simple $\int \exp(-\exp(-x^2))\mathrm dx$ does not seem to have a closed form, so I'm even more doubtful that your integral is tractable. You may have to content yourself with numerics.

Answer (score 1):

Having a closed form for integral of an incomplete gamma function should be a big deal(!), but having a numerical approximation is simple. Define:

```
f[k_,e_,limit_]:=NIntegrate[Gamma[k, 0, Exp[-2 e x^2]], {x, -limit, limit}];
```

For example:

```
f[2,0.2,3]
(* 0.591563 *)
```

You can also see how `f` changes with `k` and `e`:

```
Plot[{Legended[f[k, 0.2, 3.], "e=0.2"], 
  Legended[f[k, 2., 3.], "e=2."], Legended[f[k, 5., 3.], "e=5."]}, {k,
   0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"k", "f"}]
```

[image]

and

```
Plot[{Legended[f[1, e, 3.], "k=1"], Legended[f[2, e, 3.], "k=2"], 
  Legended[f[3, e, 3.], "k=3"]}, {e, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"e", "f"}]
```

[image]

You can easily change the limit of integral to $0$ to $\infty$:

```
f[k_, e_] := NIntegrate[Gamma[k, 0, Exp[-2 e x^2]], {x, 0, Infinity}];
```

Comment: This is very helpful and detailed thanks.
Do you know if I have any chance of computing this approximate value of the integral with the integration limits being 0 and +Infinity?

I guess I can then use f as a function of k, to compute a convolution of values of f?